# Count unique text values based on criteria in other column

Tags: excel, frequency, countif, sumifs

I have two columns titled "Company" and "Department", example below. The third column is what I would like to create, but I am unsure how. I want the third column to show the number of departments for a given company, and only show that number in the first reference to the company.

[image: Click here for example]

Comment: Pivot table is ideal for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in D2 and fill down.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A2)=1, SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$999=A2)/(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$999, B$2:B$999&"", A$2:A$999, A2)+(A$2:A$999<>A2))), "")
```

[image]

Comment: How would I alter this to work with a sheet that has > 22,000 rows?

Comment: With a VBA sub procedure focused on a variant array and a dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a helper column in Column C that concatenates your two cells, you can then use a function like this:

`=if(countif($C$1:C7,C7)=1,sumif(….),"")`

If that's not an option, you'll need to use an Array which is likely not something you want to do either.

You might be able to capture your requirements with a pivottable too... Not sure.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a pivot table to get distinct count of column department.

While creating the pivot table you need to add the table to the data model so that you expose "distinct count"

(one of numerous sources: http://www.howtoexcelatexcel.com/formulas/excel-tip-how-to-count-unique-items-in-excel-pivot-table/)