# Customers per item

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns of data (Product - Column A & Customer - Column B)

Example - The product Egg appeared 20 times in Column A and was sold to 3 different customers (Bill x 10, Ben x 6, John x 4)

I need to find a formula that returns the number of customers per product into Cell E1 when I type the Product code into cell D1

Can anybody help please??

Note - the dataset is fairly large, up to 50000 rows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count unique text values based on criteria in other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051962/count-unique-text-values-based-on-criteria-in-other-column)

Comment: That's not going to scale to 50,000 rows, but that looks like a good starting point.